# Find the equation of the tangent plane to f(x,y) = yln(x) at the point (1,5)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What I've done:

$$z = f(x_0,y_0) + f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0) + f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$

$$f_x=\frac{y}{x}$$

---

$$f_y= \ln(x)$$

---

$$f(1,5) = (5)(\ln(1)) - 0$$

---

$$f_x(1,5) = y$$

---

$$f_y(1,5) =\text{ ? -> }\ln(x)\text{ or }\ln(1) = 0$$

---

and what next?

Comment: Is the point $(1,4)$ or $(1,5)?$ In any case $f_y(1,y_0)=y_0\ln 1=0.$

Answer (score 1):

If the point is $(x_0,y_0)=(1,5)$, your computations yield
$$
z=f(1,5)+f_x(1,5)(x-1)+f_y(1,5)(y-5)
$$
that is
$$
z=5\ln0+\frac{5}{1}(x-1)+\ln0\cdot(y-5)
$$
and finally
$$
z=5(x-1)
$$
If the point is $(1,4)$ just substitute throughout and you get $z=4(x-1)$.

Given $f_y=y/x$, in order to compute the partial derivative at $(1,5)$, you substitute *both* variables:
$$
f_y(1,5)=\frac{5}{1}=5
$$
not $y$.